# TypeScript restrict method chaining on class instantiation

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example class:

```js
class Example {
  public foo(): Pick<this, "bar" | "baz"> {
    return this;
  }
  public bar(): Pick<this, "baz"> {
    return this;
  }
  public baz(): string {
    return "something";
  }
}
```

Then we can do the following:

```js
const example = new Example();
example.foo().bar(); // OK
example.bar().foo(); // Error: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Pick<Example, "baz">'.
```

The above allows me to pick what methods I can chain off in the class, but is it possible to do the same from the base of the class instance. So for example, can I tell TypeScript "hey, you can only allow the base to call the method `foo` but not anything else".

For example:

```js
const example = new Example();
example.foo(); // OK
example.bar(); // Error: Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Example'.
example.baz(); // Error: Property 'baz' does not exist on type 'Example'.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you only have one "base" to enter a chain, I think you should just return a new class that handles the chain. The new class could be a `private static readonly ExampleChainBuilder = class ExampleChainBuilder { ... }` so it can have access to the class' private members.

Comment: Class statements won't work this way in TypeScript; you can use a type annotation on a variable assigned from a class *expression* to get such an effect, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WY2v3w).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: ...why would you ever want to restrict how users of your thing *chain methods*? If you don't like method chains could always just return void instead of this. What is the point of your question? If the point is that the methods need to be called in a particular order, then use a Builder pattern where the methods return an appropriate data type rather than trying to shoehorn your Builder into the type system that way.

Comment: You could probably create a static method which returns an instance of the class. To the return type, you can add your restrictions and make the constructor private.

Answer (score 0):

A return type of `asserts this is` allows changing the type of the class instance. For example:

```js
class Example {
  public foo(): asserts this is Record<"bar", never> {
  }
  public bar() {
  }
}

const example: Example = new Example();
example.foo(); // ok
example.bar(); // error
```